# How do I make ajax stop with setTimeout in a webchat to show a chatline every set time even if they were submitted at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I make "case 'chatLine':" wait a certain time before sending the params to print on the screen. I have tried to place a `setTimeout()` but it does not wait for the time that I want it to. I have even made an ajax function to go into a PHP file that would `sleep(10)` and then return to the main render case but it can't do this. Don't know why...

How would I set the time to read a chatline every 10 seconds? For example, if 2 or more chatline get submitted at the same time for it to shown in 10 seconds each of them by the order that they went in.
lines submitted at the exact same time would be Line1, Line2, and line3:

LINE 1: HELLO

//10 seconds after show LINE 2

LINE 2: HI

//10 seconds after show LINE 3

LINE 3: GREAT

the wait.class.php file is

the full code for this is at:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-css-jquery/

That is all I did in the PHP file.
What I am making is a web chat in ajax and I want to be able to show

```
// The login method hides displays the
// user's login data and shows the submit form

login : function(name,gravatar){

    chat.data.name = name;
    chat.data.gravatar = gravatar;
    $('#chatTopBar').html(chat.render('loginTopBar',chat.data));

    $('#loginForm').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#submitForm').fadeIn();
        $('#chatText').focus();
    });

},

// The render method generates the HTML markup
// that is needed by the other methods:

render : function(template,params){



    function wait(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/classes/wait.class.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'text': params.text,
                'time': params.time
            },
        })
    }
    var arr = [];
    switch(template){
        case 'loginTopBar':
            arr = [
            '<span><img src="',params.gravatar,'" width="23" height="23" />',
            '<span class="name">',params.name,
            '</span><a href="" class="logoutButton rounded">Logout</a></span>'];
        break;

        case 'chatLine':
            arr = [
                '<div class="chat chat-',params.id,' rounded"><span class="gravatar">'+
                '<img src="',params.gravatar,'" width="23" height="23" '+
                'onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" />',
                '</span><span class="author">',params.author,
                ':</span><span class="text">',params.text,
                '</span><span class="time">',params.time,'</span></div>'];
        break;

        case 'user':
            arr = [
                '<div class="user" title="',params.name,'"><img src="',params.gravatar,
                '" width="30" height="30" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'"'+
                ' /></div>'
            ];
        break;
    }

    // A single array join is faster than
    // multiple concatenations

    return arr.join('');

},
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

1. jQuery.ajax is asynchronized so javascript code still continue to execute without waiting server response. There is a parameter to change it to synchronized but then your server will stack a lot sleep requests which eat up a lot resource. So don't use this method.
2. Your "arr" variable always has one item every time render is called so no need to use "arr" just return HTML string is ok.

Here is my solution:

1. After received data from server instead of call render right away, add "template" and "params" to a global array.

   ```
   var items = [];   
   items[] = { 'template': template, 'params': params };
   // Begin render and display data if process isn't running
   // Note: "running" variable is defined in (2.)
   if(running == false) {
       display();
   }
   ```
2. Create a "display" function do two things: call "render" to create HTML string and decide when to add that string to document.

   ```
   var running = false;
   function display() {
       running = true;
       var item = null;
       var html = [];
       while(items.length > 0) {
           item = items.shift();
           // Render HTML string
           html[] = render(item.template, item.params);
           // Stop render and output HTML data
           if(item.template == 'chatLine') {
               break;
           }
       }
       // A single array join is faster than multiple concatenations
       html = html.join('');
       // TODO: Add rendered HTML string to document
       ...
       if(items.length > 0) {
           // Call "display" again after 10 seconds
           setTimeout(display, 10000);
       } else {
           // There is no item need to render then stop process
           running = false;
           // Note: Next time received data from server
           // "display" will be called as in (1.)
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make "case 'chatLine':" wait a certain time before sending
>   the params to print on the screen.

You can use a callback function, something like

```
render : function(template,params, callback){
```

and then

```
case 'chatLine':
   setTimeout(function(){ callback(arr); }, 10000);
```

You will have to move all your logic into the function "callback" sent as a parameter. Also every other case should call the function callback.

```
render(template, params, callback);

function callback(results){
//process results, print on the screen
}
```

It's possible that I'm bad at explaining :)

Comment: within the switch() statement?

Comment: You would have to move the logic from where you used the render method inside the function that you send as a callback

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, i'm bad at understanding things, but this answer is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at script.js part five. The variable that sets the timings is `nextRequest`.

Within this portion of the code, you can set `nextRequest` depending on how long it has been since the latest chat activity. Here you can modify the timings to suit your needs.

**Excerpt From: script.js - part 5**

```
     var nextRequest = 1000;

        // 2 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 3){
            nextRequest = 2000;
        }

        if(chat.data.noActivity > 10){
            nextRequest = 5000;
        }

        // 15 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 20){
            nextRequest = 15000;
        }
```

Comment: this is the timing for getting all the chats lines

Comment: That assertion is incorrect. Chat lines that are typed into this client by the user will never hit this code path before being rendered. Can you be a little bit more specific about what chat lines you are trying to delay?